# Assembly Error - The file is in use

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm compiling a DLL at runtime and then run it:

```
private void RunDll2(string path, string typename)
{
    AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
    AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);

    Command cmd = (Command)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.FullName, typename);
    cmd.Execute();
    cmd = null;
}
```

This works one time, but if I want to compile the DLL with another code (same file) it gives me the error: File is used by another process!
Then I have to restart the application!

How can I unload the assembly when the Code in it is finished?

EDIT:

Code of the ´Command´ class:

```
using System;

namespace NWT_Projekt
{
    public interface Command
    {
        void Execute();
    }
}
```

Code of the Dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NWT_Projekt
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class TestClass : NWT_Projekt.Command
    {
        public MainForm f;

        public TestClass()
        {
            f = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
        }

        void wait(int sec)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sec / 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }


        public void Execute()
        {
            //Here is different code each time I compile it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to unload AppDomain for it to release the assembly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your main domain is resolving the Script.dll assembly and now has that file in-use, creating and then unloading the new domain (Scrip.dll) doesn't release the the link the original (main) app domain has on it.

Here are some ideas as I have done this before:

1) Have the main app domain create a NEW sub directory that contains the assembly.  The main app domain can **COPY** the assembly and all necessary private assemblies from the directory you are currently using.  Now instead of loading the assembly that you are currently using (that results in a lock) use the copied assembly in the newly created sub-directory.  You could name the sub-directory a GUID or something random.
2) Get real deep and create your own shadow assembly mechanism, I thing #1 is the simplest way to go.  ASP.NET does a similar thing, it doesn't actually use the assemblies in the \bin folder it creates a temp folder and copies them.  This allows you to recompile and deploy to a new version.

Here is a link I have used in the past:  http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm

Comment: This doesn't work!
Error:
`CS0016: to output file 'XXXXX \ Script.dll' could not be written - 'The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process. '`

Comment: is that assembly the one that contains the RunDll2 method?

Comment: WHAT?! :D
IDK why it doesn't work! If I just compile the code and don't execute it with the Function `RunDll2` then I can compile it without errors as often as I want! But If I run this function it doesn't work!

Comment: I can understand an issue if you are trying to compile the assembly that contains the RunDll2() as that is is still executing.

Comment: I think your issue is that the running process has loaded this assembly during it's assembly probing phase, you need to release the lock on the assembly that the appdomain that is resolving the Script assembly.

Comment: How do I do this? I'm new to assemblies and Runtime compiling! :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48410/discussion-between-user3001407-and-t-mckeown)

Comment: Ok, it works now! I just create the Dll file with the filename `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DllD" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".dll")`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the [Unload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then register to the [DomainUnload Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to react accordingly.

So in your case you could do the following:

```
private void RunDll2(string path, string typename)
{
    AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
    AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);

    Command cmd = (Command)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.FullName, typename);
    cmd.Execute();
    cmd = null;

    //Unload the Domain
    AppDomain.Unload(newDomain); 
}
```

You could take it a step further if you wish and react to this when the `DomainUnloads` event fires.

`newDomain.DomainUnload += (a, b) => Console.WriteLine("Unloaded");`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to use [Shadow Copying Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

basically as you have found out, .NET locks loaded dlls.  Shadow copying actually copies these dlls into a temporary location and then loads those copies into your app domain.